# P(X<Y|Z=t) where Z=min(X,Y)

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, extreme-value, conditioning

Lets X and Y be uniform random variable where $x \in [0,a]$ and $y \in [0,b]$ where a < b. We design $Z=\min(X,Y)$.

I know that the CDF of Z is $P(Z<z)=1-\frac{(a-z)(b-z)}{ab}$
And by conditioning, I can compute $P(X<Y)=\int_0^a{\frac{b-t}{b}\frac{1}{a}dt}=\frac{b^2-(b-a)^2}{2ab}$

But, How can I get the $P(X<Y|Z=z)?$

Answer (score 3):

Your derivation is 95% of the work for the unconditional case. Does this picture make sense? Is the answer relatively clear by seeing it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$P(X<Y,Z=z)=\int _0^z{\frac{b-s}{ab}}=\frac{b^2-(b-z)^2}{2ab}$ 
then 
$P(X<Y|Z=z)=\frac{P(X<Y, Z=z)}{P(Z<z)}=\frac{b^2-(b-z)^2}{2ab} \cdot \frac{ab}{ab-(b-z)(a-z)}=\frac{b^2-(b-z)^2}{ab-(b-z)(a-z)}$

Comment: Is my own answer correct?